# Update max_map_count for ElasticSearch docker container Mac host

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, containers, docker-container

I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/elasticsearch/) container to start `elasticsearch` in `docker`. In accordance with the [manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/vm-max-map-count.html) I have to update `max_map_count` to start the container

> sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

but.. I can update it in my host (container) AFTER I start it while I'm unable to start it. Am I doing something wrong?

> ERROR: bootstrap checks failed max virtual memory areas
>   vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]

If I try to do it on my host machine (which is Mac) I get the following error.

> sysctl: unknown oid 'vm.max_map_count'

Docker engine installs the Lunix VM where all containers are running. So the command to increase the limit should be executed for the Linux host, not for the Mac.

How can I access Linux VM via terminal installed by the Docker engine?

Comment: You increased the vm max map count as a root user right ?

Comment: yes, updated the command. But was executed for the host (Mac OS), not for the container OS (Linux) and it seems that it's required to be done for guest OS (container OS where the ES is setup).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## On Docker Toolbox

If you are in docker toolbox try the docker client from terminal and then make the configs:

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
exit
```

## On Docker For Mac:

The vm_max_map_count setting must be set within the xhyve virtual machine:

```
$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

If it asks you for a username and passwordLog in with root and no password.

If it just has a blank screen, press RETURN.

Then configure the sysctl setting as you would for Linux:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Exit by Control-A Control-\.

Se the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode).

#### Persistence

In some cases, this change does not persist across restarts of the VM. So, while `screen`'d into, edit the file `/etc/sysctl.d/00-alpine.conf` and add the parameter `vm.max_map_count=262144` to the end of file.

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: just for completion: Be aware that this change is on the host OS and NOT inside the container. Containers share the same kernel as the host OS and for that reason it's working. On OSX the "docker host OS" is a VM which is wrapped by the docker-machine cli.

Comment: you ask docker automatically [sets some environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) when creating a Linux container.

`docker run -e "MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144" ....`

Comment: @Octavio Question: I can't seem to edit that file, it keeps erroring out with `File is read-only`. I think it's something with xhyve being a read-only filesystem but my Docker/xhyve-fu is not nearly strong enough. How did you edit that file?

Comment: When I hit `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty` I go not such file or directory.

Comment: @Ragnar run `find ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/ -name 'tty'`. Mine was at `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` on High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: As @Pierce mentioned the file system is read only now: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2389#issuecomment-356547597

Comment: Is there another way of persisting this now?

Comment: Now you can change the virtual memory from the docker desktop GUI. Preferences -> Resources -> Swap -> Apply and Restart.

Comment: This works for `podman`, too:
podman machine ssh;
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144;
exit

Answer (score 25):

## On Latest Docker For Mac (Version 18.06.0-ce-mac70):

```
$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
```

On the blank screen, press RETURN.

Then configure the sysctl setting as you would for Linux:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Exit by Control-A Control-\

Comment: How can this be persisted across a reboot?

Comment: I cannot `screen`. I get `Cannot exec '/Users/arielpontes/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty': Permission denied`. `sudo` doesn't work either. The file exists but apparently cannot be executed no matter what.

Comment: @Ariel were you able to resolve this issue because I am facing the same challenge right now

Comment: @iChux in Docker Desktop, go to Preferences, after, Resources and change the Swap value

Comment: @iChux ultimately the only thing that worked for me was adding `bootstrap.system_call_filter=false` in the elasticsearch environment in my docker-compose file.

Answer (score 8):

To make it work with Mac Sonoma 14.0 + Docker Desktop 25.0, follow these steps:

- Enable Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon in Settings -> General
- Disable Access experimental features in Settings -> Features in development -> Experimental Features
- Run the following commands (see https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4822)

> `docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh`
>
> `/ # sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`
>
> `vm.max_map_count = 262144`

Comment: only one working solution
MAC Ventura 13.6
Docker Desktop 4.25.0

Comment: Sonoma 14.1 + Docker 24.0.6 worked as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For those using `Docker Desktop` on windows 10 you have to execute:

`wsl -d docker-desktop` in the command line before `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

Answer (score 2):

For mac users you might have a problem connecting to docker VM, therefore you should run this command to enter the shell of the Docker VM:

```
docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh
```

GitHub issue description: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4822

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it on my Mac (Sonoma 14.0) without dealing with vm.max_map_count by downgrading Docker Desktop to v.23 (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17120-ce-mac49-2018-01-19)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35197578)

Comment: I confirm it does not work on Mac Sonoma + Docker Desktop 4.25.0 (126437). @Gleb can you provide details on how to fix it in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

## Podman Desktop for Mac OS

For those of us having the same problem with Podman Desktop, we have to update the settings of the virtual machine that Podman runs for running containers on Macs.

### Steps...

#### Login into the Podman VM

From a terminal on your mac:

```
$ podman machine ssh
```

#### Edit Default `/etc/sysctl.conf` File

Using `sudo` edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add the `vm.max_map_count = 262144` property.

```
$ sudo echo "vm.max_map_count = 262144" | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.conf
```

After exiting the podman virtual machine you should be able to run the ElasticSearch container:

```
$ podman run --name es01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.8.0
```

I would then recommend stopping Podman Desktop and rebooting your mac.  Then restarting Podman Desktop and trying to run the ElasticSearch container again.  It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Folder has been moved and this is the new location -

$screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty

and then

sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

For those who use docker desktop on mac, you can easily increase the memory by the following steps:

1. click on docker desktop -> preferences...
2. navigate to 'Resources'
3. change the memory to whatever you need
4. click on 'Apply & Restard'

Comment: This does not resolve the max vm issue.

Answer (score -3):

If you have installed Docker from [docker's Mac installer](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/) then you will have Docker desktop installed(also includes includes Docker Engine, Docker CLI client, Docker Compose, Notary, Kubernetes, and Credential Helper.)

Here is what Docker desktop looks like in 2021 where you can change memory/swap or any other resources.

#### Step 1 - click on docker's preferences as shown below.

[image]

#### Step 2 - Click on resources tab, here you can tweak the resources and finally click on "Apply and Restart" button.

[image]

Please ignore configuration what I made. You can set based on your requirement.

Comment: From that configuration screen you cannot change the vm.max_map_count